# Bevel Object Question

Tags: bevel

Hello whenever i tried to bevel my object using the fast carve add-on option Bevel object in blender 2.8 my geometry got mess i have attached the pic of my object with bevel modifier but its not looking good any tips how to fix this as i not getting the desired bevel shape below is the image for more clarification

[image]

here the image of my bevel modifier setting

[image]

---

here the image of my bevel modifier setting
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/GioiJ.png

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This can have many reasons. Please add an image of your *bevel modifier* settings, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Try changing the *Width Method* to from *Offset* to *Width* if you're looking for an even bevel all the way around. Also, make sure you've applied scale for the object as unevenly scaled objects can cause weird results.

Answer (score 3):

Your mesh has very tight corners for *limited* Beveling.

Some suggestions that could help

- Change the *Outer Mitter type* to arc/patch. Creates ugly n-gons, but sometimes helps.
- Apply bevel to *all* edges. You're currently beveling only some, which results in tight geometry.
- Use *Subdivision modifier* with low unlimited bevel. Clean geometry but higher polycount.

*Just to illustrate*

[image]